# Can developer keep track of stats of app? - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, statistics

I have made a trivia game app.  Is there any way to keep track of, without the user knowing, stats like the following:

- How many times a user has played a certain quiz
- Overall correct percentage of questions of each quiz and of all quizzes combined
- How many times the user ran out of time on a question
- etc etc

I would love to be able to keep track of this so I can monitor data constantly to see, for example, if more time is needed on questions because they keep running out of time, etc etc.  Right now I don't need a server or any internet interaction to play this game so if that is needed to do what I am asking above, please say that.

Comment: "_without the user knowing_": You should consider having a privacy statement or something stating what data you are collecting and for what purpose in your application. Most users will not mind and the other who care would be reassured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Google Analytics for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/). Internet connection will be necesary.

Comment: i've just added the link :)

Comment: I am new to servers and such.  Would I have to maintain a server to do this?  How much per month on estimate would that be?

Comment: No, You just need put GA lib into your app, and report request.

Comment: So to go the ````Google Analytics for Android```` route, it would not cost me any sort of monthly fee?

Comment: OMG - please read their terms, should I copy and paste them here?

Comment: no, with GA your app will send data to google's servers ... then you will be able to see gathered data in GA console

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a number of ways, all using web services though.  It's up to you whether you want to store the statistics on the phone and then send these, or just send each individual statistic on game completion.

You would need a server to act as the web service endpoint which would then be called (using SOAP/REST probably) from the phone either nightly (if you stored the stats on a localdb on the phone) or after each game.

I'd recommend nightly or intervals rather than clogging up the phone owners bandwidth sending stats :)

Comment: Arg, all options use web services.  :(  Well, lets say I do end up getting a server to act as a web service.  What do you suggest is the best route?

Comment: Dont despair, write a small NodeJS/Rails server and host it at heroku, they offer free hosting.

Comment: @Machinarius - what if I don't know NodeJS or Rails?  Is there any sample servers written that I could piggyback off of?  I am new to this sort of thing.

Comment: I dare to say that nodejs with connect and postgreSQL will allow you to code your server in around an hour. Assuming you already know javascript, that is.